# Set auto height and width in CSS/HTML for different screen sizes

Tags: html, css

I have **2 issues** with this layout :

1. `.feature_content` (*grey background*) adapt it's height and width to different screen sizes. Right now, on big screens `.feature_content` is far from the footer.
2. There is a horizontal scrollbar that I want to remove regardless to the screen size.

**I want to :** adapt `.feature_content` to the remaining height and remove the horizontal scrollbar.

Here is a **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/Apynn/1/)**

And my code :

**HTML** :

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="header">Header added just for demonstration purposes</div>
    <div id="content">Your content goes here
        <div class="featured_content"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="footer">Footer here</div>
```

**CSS** :

```
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
}
body, html {
    width:100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}
div {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    border:5px solid black;
}
#header {
    background-color:orange;
}
#container {
    background:blue;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    height: auto !important;
}
#content {
    background:pink;
    padding-bottom: 100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
}
#footer {
    bottom: 0;
    box-shadow: 0 -1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    height: 70px;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 100000;
    background:green;
}
.featured_content {
    min-height: 750px;
    max-height: 750px;
    width:200px;
    background-color:grey;
    position:fixed;
    margin:auto 0px;
    margin-top: 150px;
}
```

Comment: Is .featured_content set to `position: fixed` because you actually need it to be in a fixed position independent from scrolling or because you couldn't figure out any other way for it to be to the right of your other content?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what do you want? [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nppXQ/). Try to shrink the browser's window and you'll see that the elements will be ordered.

What I used? Flexible Box Model or Flexbox.

Just add the follow CSS classes to your container element (in this case `div#container`):

`flex-init-setup` and `flex-ppal-setup`.

Where:

1. **flex-init-setup** means *flexbox init setup*; and
2. **flex-ppal-setup** means *flexbox principal setup*

Here are the CSS rules:

```
 .flex-init-setup {
     display: -webkit-box;
     display: -moz-box;
     display: -webkit-flex;
     display: -ms-flexbox;
     display: flex;
 }
 .flex-ppal-setup {
     -webkit-flex-flow: column wrap;
     -moz-flex-flow: column wrap;
     flex-flow: column wrap;
     -webkit-justify-content: center;
     -moz-justify-content: center;
     justify-content: center;
 }
```

Be good,
Leonardo

Comment: Flexbox isn't *under revision*, it is a Candidate Recommendation (meaning it is considered stable enough for Browser vendors to begin implementing it).  Browser support isn't good at the moment, either (no IE<10).  You've botched up your properties in `.flex-ppal-setup` (no 2009 Flexbox implementation supports wrapping, and you're missing the 2009/2012 properties that correspond to justify-content).

Comment: I didn't know that about the difference between *under revision* and *Candidate Recommendation*. Thanks for the info! But I don't understand what you mean about the oroperties in `.flex-ppal-setup` =/

Answer (score 1):

///UPDATED DEMO 2 WATCH SOLUTION////

I hope that is the solution you're looking for!  [DEMO1](http://jsfiddle.net/Pasia/AS88N/) [DEMO2](http://jsfiddle.net/Pasia/GumPE/5/)

With that solution the only scrollbar in the page is on your contents section in the middle! 
In that section build your structure with a sidebar or whatever you want!

You can do that with that code here:

```
<div class="navTop">
<h1>Title</h1>
    <nav>Dynamic menu</nav>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <section>THE CONTENTS GOES HERE</section>
</div>
<footer class="bottomFooter">
    Footer
</footer>
```

With that css:

```
.navTop{
width:100%;
border:1px solid black;
float:left;
}
.container{
width:100%;
float:left;
overflow:scroll;
}
.bottomFooter{
float:left;
border:1px solid black;
width:100%;
}
```

And a bit of jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  function setHeight() {
    var top = $('.navTop').outerHeight();
    var bottom = $('footer').outerHeight();
    var totHeight = $(window).height();
    $('section').css({ 
      'height': totHeight - top - bottom + 'px'
    });
  }

  $(window).on('resize', function() { setHeight(); });
  setHeight();
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Pasia/AS88N/) 1

If you don't want jquery

```
<div class="row">
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <nav>NAV</nav>
</div>

<div class="row container">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="sidebar">
            SIDEBAR
        </div>
        <div class="contents">
            CONTENTS
        </div>
    </div>
    <footer>Footer</footer>
</div>
```

CSS

```
*{
margin:0;padding:0;    
}
html,body{
height:100%;
width:100%;
}
body{
display:table;
}
.row{
width: 100%;
background: yellow;
display:table-row;
}
.container{
background: pink;
height:100%; 
}
.content {
display: block;
overflow:auto;
height:100%;
padding-bottom: 40px;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
footer{ 
position: fixed; 
bottom: 0; 
left: 0; 
background: yellow;
height: 40px;
line-height: 40px;
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
}
.sidebar{
float:left;
background:green;
height:100%;
width:10%;
}
.contents{
float:left;
background:red;
height:100%;
width:90%;
overflow:auto;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Pasia/GumPE/5/) 2

Comment: it is still not working for me. It is still the same problem :-(

Comment: Unless the OP adds the javascript tag, it's best to only provide pure CSS solutions (even when the JS tag is added, pure CSS > javascript).

Comment: Can you be more specific as to what *doesn't work*?  Because it looks like it works to me.

Comment: okay... what problem is : content_features is perfectly sticky to the footer in my laptop screen but it is far from the footer in a big screen. and it is also over the footer with a scrollbar in another small laptop screen. my layout looks fine but features are not in the same position of different screen sizes.

Comment: ^ @media(min-width: 720px){.something{width:720px}}

Answer (score 0):

Using bootstrap with a little bit of customization, the following seems to work for me:

I need 3 partitions in my container and I tried this:

CSS:

```
.row.content {height: 100%; width:100%; position: fixed; }
.sidenav {
  padding-top: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #cecece;
  height: 100%;
}
.midnav {
  padding: 0px;
}
```

HTML:

```
  <div class="container-fluid text-center"> 
    <div class="row content">
    <div class="col-md-2 sidenav text-left">Some content 1</div>
    <div class="col-md-9 midnav text-left">Some content 2</div>
    <div class="col-md-1 sidenav text-center">Some content 3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```