# Flex 4 - How to set auto height and width in flex for different screen sizes

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4

How to set auto height and width for different screen sizes in flex?

I need what they did [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17263064/how-to-set-auto-height-and-width-css-in-html-for-different-screen-sizes) exactly, but in flex. And I don't have clear idea about percentHeight and percentwidth. Anyone can explain about it? And please share some links to learn about it.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

What have you tried so far? you use percentheight/percentwidth if it is in AS3. in mxml, you simply assign it like width="100%". thats because in as3, it doesnt understand "%" and only accepts integers, so you do percentWidth=100;

Comment: I want answer like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17263064/how-to-set-auto-height-and-width-css-in-html-for-different-screen-sizes) , but in flex